# Glpk java crash

Tags: java, dll, jvm, native, glpk

I am using Glpk java to solve a LP relaxation.

The weird thing is that sometimes it works but sometimes JVM crashes. And when it crashes I have this error:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffedcbb4d92, 
pid=16584, tid=17184
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_66-b18) (build 1.8.0_66 b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.66-b18 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
 # C  [ntdll.dll+0x14d92]
```

Sometimes it crashes silently, and when it does it's on a random native function from the glpk DLL file (i.e glp_simplex and glp_delete_prob).

Here is a part of my code:

```
        // Allocate memory
        ind = GLPK.new_intArray(problem.getNbrConstraints());
        val = GLPK.new_doubleArray(problem.getNbrConstraints());

        // Create rows
        GLPK.glp_add_rows(lp, problem.getNbrConstraints());


        // Set row details
        for (int i = 0; i < problem.getNbrConstraints(); i++) {
            GLPK.glp_set_row_name(lp, i + 1, "c" + (i + 1));
            GLPK.glp_set_row_bnds(lp, i + 1, GLPKConstants.GLP_DB, 0, problem.getB(i));

            for (int j = 0; j < problem.getNbrVaribles(); j++) {
                GLPK.intArray_setitem(ind, j + 1, j + 1);
                GLPK.doubleArray_setitem(val, j + 1, problem.getItem(j).getRessource(i));
            }
            GLPK.glp_set_mat_row(lp, i + 1, problem.getNbrVaribles(), ind, val);
        }

        // Free memory
        GLPK.delete_intArray(ind);
        GLPK.delete_doubleArray(val);

        // Define objective
        GLPK.glp_set_obj_name(lp, "z");
        GLPK.glp_set_obj_dir(lp, GLPKConstants.GLP_MAX);
        for (int j = 0; j < problem.getNbrVaribles(); j++) {
            GLPK.glp_set_obj_coef(lp, j + 1, problem.getItem(j).getProfit());
        }

        // Write model to file
        GLPK.glp_write_lp(lp, null, "lp.lp");

        // Solve model
        parm = new glp_smcp();
        GLPK.glp_init_smcp(parm);
        ret = GLPK.glp_simplex(lp, parm);

        // Free memory
        GLPK.glp_delete_prob(lp);
```

Any ideas ?

Thank you.

Comment: I see the same issue. In my case the exception is raised during the deletion of the problem. Maybe adding the log of the crash will help others to give you hints

Answer (score 0):

> ind = GLPK.new_intArray(problem.getNbrConstraints());

As described in doc/glpk.pdf the index 0 is not used by glpk.

So you arrays should have one additional element

```
ind = GLPK.new_intArray(problem.getNbrConstraints() + 1);
val = GLPK.new_doubleArray(problem.getNbrConstraints() + 1);
```